# Transparent Logo for PowerPoint template

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am looking for a way to create a template in which a transparent logo
is always on top of an image placeholder.

Google doesn't seem to be very helpful in that area.

What I have found out so far is that PowerPoint always puts the placeholder on top of the eventual slide, and it seems there is no easy way to send a placeholder behind a logo that is placed already in the master.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thx Guys.

Comment: Not certain, but a thought... change the slide *background* to be your placeholder maybe? That *will* but it behind all items, including master slide items.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct with your findings, if you place an image in your Slide Master the Placeholders rule - so use a place holder in your layer stack.
I find that a Web Image Placeholder is a suitable element to use as its not a commonly used type of placeholder.

- Create your Logo asset in .png or better still .svg
- Place Web Image Placeholder in Slide Master and 'Fill' with Logo Asset
- When you use your Layout, the Placeholder will retain the position in the stack.

Refer to the [Brandwares website](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/08/logos-over-photos-best-practices/) for a detailed explanation and more